# Get strong outer element from selection in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i want to get the strong element of the getSeletion() Element in Javascript. i have a html like this:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  <strong>TEST</strong>
</div>
```

i have test it with this javascript code

```
function getSelectionParentElement() {
        var parentEl = null, sel;
        if (window.getSelection) {
            sel = window.getSelection();
            if (sel.rangeCount) {
                parentEl = sel.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
                if (parentEl.nodeType != 1) {
                    parentEl = parentEl.parentNode;
                }
            }
        } else if ( (sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
            parentEl = sel.createRange().parentElement();
        }
        return parentEl;
    }
```

and with window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentElement or selection.getRangeAt(0).startContainer.parentNode

but it only returns the div not the strong element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple. I use Rangy. It has the functionality for the major browser. you can get the element with: rangy.getSelection().focusNode.parentElement.localName

Answer (score 0):

From my testing, your `getSelectionParentElement()` function *is* returning the "strong" element when the selection is confined to the strong element. See this fiddle demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/akfg87n6/

If you select only letters from TEST, then it returns the strong element, while if you select letters from the div (I added "before" and "after" text to make that possible) then it returns the div element.

This is as expected according to the `commonAncestorContainer()` documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Range:

> Range.commonAncestorContainer [Read only] Returns the deepest Node that contains the startContainer and endContainer nodes.

When the entirety of your text selection resides within the strong element, then the strong element is the deepest Node that contains the start and end container nodes (which, incidentally, are both the strong element in that case). But if the selection extends outside of the strong element into the div content, then the strong element no longer contains the entirety of the selection, and so `commonAncestorContainer()` must return a shallower element, which will be the div if the text selection is still confined within the div content.

Comment: Okay. I tested it with chrome and firefox. Firefox returned div and chrome return strong...

Comment: I'm working in Firefox, and it returns strong for me when my text selection is confined to the strong element content (i.e. the TEST text).

Comment: my version ist 32.0.3

Comment: mine is 35.0, that could be it